# Trapezoidal Error is lower than Simpson Error, Find some condition?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, numerical-methods, simpsons-rule

I find a problem that have no idea for it. 
in calculating $ \int^{1}_{0} (x^6-mx^5)dx $ we know Trapezoidal Error is lower 
than Simpson Error. what is the range of $m$?

Solution: $\frac {217}{210} < m< \frac {263}{238}$

Option:

1) $\frac {15}{14} < m< \frac {85}{74}$

2) $\frac {23}{48} < m< \frac {57}{63}$

3) $\frac {237}{215} < m< \frac {279}{193}$

4) $\frac {217}{210} < m< \frac {263}{238}$

How this calculated?

Comment: Is the number of subdivisions specified?

Comment: @AndréNicolas no is not defined.

Comment: Does your course distinguish between for example Trapezoidal Rule (3 pts) and Composite Trapezoidal Rule (more points)?

Comment: No, it's not mentioned. @AndréNicolas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are expected to compute the integral three ways:  exactly, using a single interval of the trapezoidal rule, and using a single application of Simpsion's rule.  The exact value is $E=\frac 17-\frac m6$.  The trapezoidal value is $T=\frac12(f(0)+f(1))=\frac 12(1-m)$.  The Simpson's value is $S=\frac 16(f(0+4f(\frac 12)+f(1))=\frac 16(\frac 1{16}-\frac m8+1-m)=\frac {17}{96}-\frac {9m}{48}$  The error of the trapezoidal method is $|E-T|$ and the error of Simpson's method is $|E-S|$  You are expected to find the range of $m$ such that $|E-T| \lt |E-S|$. [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cm%2F3-5%2F14%7C%3D%7Cm%2F48%2B1%2F7-17%2F96%7C) reports the range as $\frac {31}{30} \lt m \lt \frac {263}{238}$, which is choice $4$.  Mark your book down for not reducing $\frac {217}{210}$ to lowest terms.

Added:  In the inequality $|\frac m3 -\frac 5{14}|\lt |\frac m{48}-\frac {23}{672}|$ each side represents a V shaped graph where the point of the V is the place where it equals zero.  The Vs will typically have two points of intersection and the solution will either be the part of the line between them or the part outside.  To solve it, we need to find the points of intersection.  With two absolute value signs, we have four choices of the signs of the contents.  We make each assumption, solve the resulting linear equation, and check if the signs work according to our assumption.  So if the contents are both positive, we are solving $\frac m3 -\frac 5{14}=\frac m{48}-\frac {23}{672}$, which gives $m=\frac {31}{30}$.  You can plug that in and find both sides are positive as assumed, so this is one point of intersection.  Try the other three combinations and you will find the other intersection point.  Then check a value for $m$ that is between the intersection points to find the sense of the inequality.  The graph in the Alpha page I linked to should help.

Comment: What ? Would you please explain more your last sentence? my solution is correct?

Comment: The stated solution is correct, but I know students are often asked to make sure to submit answers which are fractions in lowest terms so an answer of $\frac {217}{210}$ would be penalized.  I got $\frac {31}{30}$ from Alpha and it took a moment to realize they are the same.

Comment: sorry I misunderstand how range reported by alpha is equal to my answer?

Comment: I asked Alpha to find the points where the two errors are equal.  It also provided a graph showing $|E-T| \lt |E-S|$ in that range, so that shows the range of $m$  I added a sentence about why this is what we want to solve

Comment: 1) it's not possible to calculate by hand?   2) lower bound is 31/30 ? ! is differ from my solution ?

Comment: Certainly it is possible to calculate it by hand.  It is a linear equation with two absolute value signs.  You can try the possibilities for the absolute value signs and get an $m$ for each, then check which two are real.  I just let Alpha do that work.  Do you see  $\frac {217}{210}=\frac {31}{30}$ ?  Just divide top and bottom by $7$

Comment: yeah I get it completely, but my challenge is when calculate by hand. okey +1, thanks but I want to learn by hand :)

Comment: The exact result reported by Alpha is the equation to solve$$|\frac m3 -\frac 5{14}|=|\frac m{48}-\frac {23}{672}|$$  It is not hard to solve, but the constants make it messy.  If you had understood the problem to here and the only problem was how to solve it, you should have said so.

Comment: yes, your nice detail and nice answer. the remaining option is solve this equation. would you please let me know ?

Comment: Would you please let me know how solve this equation ?

Comment: I try more and more but couldn't solve it by hand ! if you have enough time, is so nice if you complete the part of calculation of equation? I want to learn it and calculate by hand. thanks Professor.